# How can I get the icon to display for a file from a Java app?

Tags: java, desktop, icons

Is it possible from a Java desktop app to find the icon to display for a given file, perhaps based on it's mime type? Specifically I want to ask the host OS for the icon to display so it can match what the user would expect to see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some example [here](http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-file-type-icon-with-java.html). The relevant code would be:

```
FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();    
Icon icon = view.getSystemIcon(file);
```

**Edit** (included comment) The official help page is [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon(java.io.File).

Comment: Would be worth linking to here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon(java.io.File)

Answer (score 2):

AS far as I know the only thing you can do is using the JTree's DefaultTreeCellRenderer. You can read more in the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html).

I'll give you a few examples here. I haven't used it in a while so you will need to dig a little deeper to get what you want.

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults( );

Icon computerIcon = defaults.getIcon( "FileView.computerIcon" );
Icon floppyIcon   = defaults.getIcon( "FileView.floppyDriveIcon" );
Icon diskIcon     = defaults.getIcon( "FileView.hardDriveIcon" );
Icon fileIcon     = defaults.getIcon( "FileView.fileIcon" );
Icon folderIcon   = defaults.getIcon( "FileView.directoryIcon" );
```